# How to setup OpenVPN to PFsense?

Tags: vpn, pfsense, pfsense-2

How to setup OpenVPN to PFsense?

My OpenVPN server used Angristan Openvpn-install, so I need to add there 3 lines to

> Advanced Configuration -> Custom options

```
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
```

Angristan Openvpn-install: https://github.com/Angristan/OpenVPN-install

Comment: Welcome to Network Engineering!  You might get a better/faster answer if you ask this question on [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PfSense already have options to setup a OpenVPN Client or peer to peer, you can setup using the wizard of pfsense, in case of OpenVPN Client, you'll need to install the client-export package.